# Accessing ssh user management console from BlueHost cPanel

Tags: ssh, putty, cpanel

I created a private key and configured a PuTTy session to use it; however, when opening a session, providing my password, and submitting, I'm informed that `Shell access is not enabled on your account!`. Providing an inaccurate password provides a different error, so I know the connection is being made.

All resources I consult suggest going to Manage SSH Access in cPanel for the user (the one, I believe, defined at the BlueHost level) to enable shell access, but I can't find that section, and I'm wondering if either BlueHost or cPanel has been updated.

Is it a problem requiring WHM access? I can't find a clear access point for that from my cPanel, either.

Comment: So have you enabled shell access on the account. It’s probably disabled due to your share hosting environment. Contact your hosting provider to see if it can be enabled